# Why does this jquery onClick event not get activated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Essentially, I'm building a quiz where at the end of the quiz, when you click results, I change the class of a button from nextquestion to showResults. However, the issue is that even after I change the class, when I click showResults, it's going into the nextquestion onClick() event and never even goes into the showResults. I inspect the element, and the button's class is most definitely showResults, so why is this still occurring?

```
$(".nextquestion").click(function ()
{
    if (questionnumberindex < NUM_OF_CHOICES)
    {
        var newQuestion = '<form>' + '<p> Question' + (questionnumberindex + 1) + ': ' + questionholders[questionnumberindex].question + '</p>';
        var bob = questionholders[0].choices[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < questionholders[questionnumberindex].choices.length; ++i)
        {
            newQuestion += '<input type="radio" name="Q' + questionnumberindex + '" value="' + questionholders[questionnumberindex].choices[i] + '">' + questionholders[questionnumberindex].choices[i] + '<br>';
        }
        newQuestion += "</form>";
        questionnumberindex++;
        userAnswers.push($('form input[type=radio]:checked').val());
        $(".questioncontainer").html(newQuestion);
    }
    else
    {
        $(".questioncontainer").text("Quiz Finished!");
        $(".nextquestion").text("See your Results!");
        $(".nextquestion").addClass("showResults");
        $(".nextquestion").removeClass("nextquestion");
    }


});

$(".showResults").click(function ()
{
    var numCorrect = 0;
    //calculate number of answered correctly
    var totalQuestions = questionholders.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++)
    {
        if (userAnswers[i] == questionholders[i].correct)
        {
            numCorrect++;
        }
    }
    var percentageRight = numCorrect / totalQuestions;
    //display all the questions
    var displayAllQuestions = "You got " + numCorrect + "/" + totalQuestions + "correct!";
    for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++)
    {
        var currentQuestion = "Question " + i + ": " + questionholders[i].question + "<br>";
        for (var j = 0; j < questionholders[i].choices.length; j++)
        {
            currentQuestion += "<p>" + questionholders[i].choices[j] + "</p>"
        }
        currentQuestion += "<br>";
        displayAllQuestions += currentQuestion;
    }


    $(".showResults").remove();
    $(".questioncontainer").html(displayAllQuestions);
})
```

});

Comment: I think you have an extra `});` at the end of your code...

Comment: Make sure that your button has the right class.  If you want to grab id use "#nextQuestion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the code to bind the events to the classes `showResults` and `nextQuestion`, jQuery finds the current items on the page with those classes and applies the function. Since nothing on the page has `showResults` until the end of the questions, the `showResults` click function will not be bound to anything.

One solution would be to bind the `showResults` event inside of the `nextQuestion` event:

```
$(".nextquestion").on("click.NextQuestion", function(){
    if(questionnumberindex < NUM_OF_CHOICES) {
        //insert Next Question Code Here
    }
    else {
        $(".questioncontainer").text("Quiz Finished!");
        $(".nextquestion").text("See your Results!");
        $(".nextquestion").addClass("showResults");
        $(".nextquestion").removeClass("nextquestion");

        //unbind the "Next Question event:
        $(this).off("click.NextQuestion");

         //bind the Show Results event:
        $(this).on("click", function() {
            //insert Show Results Code here
        });
    }
});
```

This solution also uses event namespacing so that you can remove the NextQuestion click event without removing any other click events associated with the button.

Comment: Great, I was wondering whether jQuery was even aware of this new class's existence. Thanks for the detailed answer andthe additional namespace solution.

Comment: can you explain `.on("click.NextQuestion")`? i thought the syntax was `$(scope).on( events, selector,callback)`

Comment: Sure, [event namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) is a way to group events. In that example, `click` is the name of the event and `NextQuestion` is the name of the namespace. `NextQuestion` means absolutely nothing to the browser; it is a name I made up to pass it to jQuery so it could be referenced later.